# How can I solve the unknown property error in cplex?

Tags: cplex, opl

I am trying to solve p median problem with CPLEX 12.10. But I have unknown property "getObjvalue" error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use OPL, you can write:

```
execute
{
  writeln(cplex.getObjValue());
}
```

V in Value with upper case.